# Align subplots ylabel's in left side

Tags: matlab

In several subplots, y-axis of each subplots ticks have different values.
Each ylabel will have different alignment. 
Is there a way to fix this -- align all the ylabels to the left?

Now it is possible only manually.

```
figure(1);
subplot 411; plot([1 2],[1 1000]);     ylabel 'Label 1';
subplot 412; plot([1 2],[1 1000]);     ylabel 'Label 2';
subplot 413; plot([1 2],[0.5 0.7]);    ylabel 'Label 3';
subplot 414; plot([1 2],[-5 0.0007]);  ylabel 'Label 4';
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ia9.png)

I expected align all the ylabel's to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically align the ylabel's of your subplot there is a [File Exchange script](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41701-y-labels-alignment-in-subplots) for that (where you seem to have taken your code example from).

With your example I found that I needed to alter the code slightly.
In the file `align_Ylabels.m` I had to change line `118` from:

```
tmp_max(k)  = size(yticks{k},2);
```

to

```
tmp_max(k)  = size(char(yticks{k}),2);
```

This ensures that it actually checks the characterlength of your yaxis tick marks.

Running your example followed by the script:

```
figure(1);
subplot 411; plot([1 2],[1 1000]);     ylabel 'Label 1';
subplot 412; plot([1 2],[1 1000]);     ylabel 'Label 2';
subplot 413; plot([1 2],[0.5 0.7]);    ylabel 'Label 3';
subplot 414; plot([1 2],[-5 0.0007]);  ylabel 'Label 4';

align_Ylabels(gcf)
```

Yields the following result:
[image]

Comment: Great. I have tried that code and was not good. Now, changing line 118, as recommended, results exactly as I need. Thanks.

Comment: And that's why it is important to *always* include all steps you have tried yourself. If you would've indicated that you tried this script already I would be able to find the problem easier.